# Running a cron that first

Tags: server, bash, cron, nginx

I need to run the following set of commands as a cron that would stop my nginx server, renew the letsencrypt certificate and then start the server again, but after the second command is over.

I have them like this:

```
sudo service nginx stop

sudo certbot renew

sudo service nginx start
```

But how do I run them as a cron?

I imagine I need to create a bash script — but when I tried to do that it would not launch, so maybe I should specify something before or after for it to be executed?

Also also, how do I ensure the last command runs only after the second one is executed?

I'm new to Ubuntu, so any advice is appreciated, even if the question seems a bit naive.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the `certbot renew` return information in its `exit` status? Check with `echo $?` immediately after `certbot renew` or check the documentation.

Comment: Yes, it's 0 if no renewal was made and 1 if it was made. However, I need the server to restart in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man 5 crontab` to learn about `root`'s crontab (so you can run your script as `root`, and not use `sudo`). Then, after deciding what you want to do when `certbot renew` fails, put *something like this* in a script somewhere, invoke it with `sudo` until it works, then invoke it from `root`'s `crontab`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# **warning! ** Untested code 
#
# tell nginx to stop
service nginx stop
# did it stop? exit status 0 => running, 3 => not
status=$(start-stop-daemon --status nginx --pidfile=/run/nginx.pid;echo $?)
while [[ $status -eq 0 ]] ; do
    # wait a tenth of a second
    sleep 0.1 
    status=$(start-stop-daemon --status nginx --pidfile=/run/nginx.pid;echo $?)
done
# Note: If nginx never stops, this will wait forever.
#
certbot renew
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 1 ]] ; then
    service nginx start
else
    whatever you do when certbot renew fails
fi
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for this detailed answer!